# How to unify version numbers between ClickOnce test and production applications?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application written in C#. I have created two build pipelines, one for the test environment and one for the production environment. For each application build, I use a PowerShell script that changes the version number to the current build pipeline run.

However, I currently have a problem with unifying the version numbers between the test and production applications. For example, the current version of the test application is 1.4.8.18, while the production application is 1.4.8.1. I want the version numbers to be the same, regardless of the number of builds executed.

How can I modify my PowerShell script so that the version numbers are unified between the test and production applications? Is there a way for the PowerShell script to retrieve the version number from the existing ClickOnce application (e.g. from the manifest file) and assign it to the new ClickOnce application during each build so that the version number remains the same, regardless of the number of builds executed? What are other ways to unify the version numbers between the test and production applications?

Code snippet:

```
# Get the path to the .csproj file
$projectFilePath = "path/to/csproj/file"

Write-Output $(Build.BuildNumber)

# Read the contents of the file into a string variable
$projectFileContents = Get-Content $projectFilePath

# Get the current value of ApplicationRevision
$currentVersion = [regex]::Match($projectFileContents, "<ApplicationVersion>([\dA-Za-z.%]+)</ApplicationVersion>").Groups[1].Value

# Increment the value of ApplicationRevision
$newVersion = "$(Build.BuildNumber)"

# Replace the value of ApplicationRevision with the new value
$newContents = $projectFileContents -replace "<ApplicationVersion>$currentVersion</ApplicationVersion>", "<ApplicationVersion>$newVersion</ApplicationVersion>"

# Write the updated contents back to the file
Set-Content $projectFilePath $newContents

# Display the new value of ApplicationRevision
Write-Host "ApplicationRevision has been incremented to $newVersion"
```

Comment: Are your build and test environments different projects?

Comment: No, that's the same project.

Comment: You could probably merge both pipelines into one and control the environments with a pipeline variable.

Comment: `.csproj` files are XML. Use PowerShells xml capabilities rather than (regex) string based replace